# Як найкраще перекласти "command prompt"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Оскільки дієприкметники із закінченнями -ачий, -ячий, учий, -ючий є невластивими українській мові(джерела: onlinecorrector, [ukr-mova.in.ua](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/blog/dieprukmetnuku-iz-zakinchennyamu-achuj,-yachuj,-uchuj,-yuchuj-vzhuvatu-chu-ni),
[Культура слова: Мовностилістичні поради: Навч. посібник. 2-ге вид., стереотип. — К.: Либідь, 2001. — 240 с.](http://ponomariv-kultura-slova.wikidot.com/morfologiya#toc0)) і тому *командуюючий*, *керуюючий* і подібні не підходять, *командний* я тут бачу як єдиний варіант(можливо *командувальний*) перекладу *command*. Виправіть мене, якщо я не маю рації.

Проте, я найбільше невпевнений щодо *prompt*.
[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0), [Glosbe](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/command%20prompt) дає слово *(командний) рядок*.
Декілька разів я бачив командна стрічка, проте вже не згадаю де саме.
[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_Windows) також дає має сторінку для cmd.exe Windows(Windows command prompt), де також використовує *командний рядок* як повний переклад словосполучення і *консоль операційної системи*, що мені здається не дуже коректним перекладом, оскільки жодний варіант значення українського слова *консоль* не збігається зі значенням *command prompt*(джерело: [СУМ-20 online](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=43633&page=1379))

Comment: Див. також: [«Як перекласти „command-line shell“»](/q/5807).

Comment: Я бачив це. Трохи різні поняття, хоча пов'язані.

Comment: За [термінологією Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?&searchTerm=command%20prompt&langID=799&Source=true&productid=0) _command prompt_ - це таки _командний рядок_.

Comment: @kaamos я абсолютно забув про цей словник термінів. Цікаво є ще якісь джерела, де це словосполучення перекладають? Я сподівався щось усталене знайти, хоча розумію the whole futility of this task.

Comment: @improbable можливо, ще щось із [цієї відповіді](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/56/2328) стане в нагоді. А взагалі _command line_ Microsoft теж [перекладає](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language/Search?&searchTerm=command%20line&langID=799&Source=true&productid=undefined) як _командний рядок_, хоча і дає термінам _command prompt_ і _command line_ різне визначення.

Comment: @kaamos Дуже корисно.

Comment: На парах з інформатики за те, що ви назвете command prompt командним рядком вам поставлять двійку за погане знання теми. Не треба брати переклад Мікром'якого за взірець. В подібних перекладах купа ляпів. Ще додам, що викладача, який не зверне на це увагу можна вважати некомпетентним.

Answer (score 4):

**command prompt** ,де

- command - *прикметник*
- prompt - *іменник*

[Джерело](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/command)

> an instruction to a computer to perform a particular action

інструкція комп’ютеру виконати певну дію

[Джерело](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prompt)

> a sign on a computer screen that shows that the computer is ready to
>   receive your instructions

знак на екрані комп’ютера, який показує, що комп'ютер готовий приймати ваші вказівки

> words that are spoken to an actor who has forgotten what he or she is
>   going to say during the performance of a play

слова, які вимовляються акторові, який забув, що він говоритиме під час вистави

Тобто по суті означає: "***запрошення для наказу***".

Детальніше про значення command prompt можна почитати, наприклад, [тут](https://techterms.com/definition/commandprompt):

> A command prompt is used in a text-based or "command-line" interface,
>   such as a Unix terminal or a DOS shell. It is a symbol or series of
>   characters at the beginning of a line that indicates the system is
>   ready to receive input. It other words, it prompts the user for a
>   command (hence the name).

*Запрошення для наказу використовується в текстовому чи в інтерфейсі "рядка для наказу", таких як термінал Unix чи DOS оболонка. Це є символ чи серія знаків на початку рядка які показують, що система готова приймати введення. Іншими словами, це спонукає (запрошує) користувача до наказу (звідси і назва).*

Comment: Може вже краще _[запрошення до введення команди](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=command+prompt&dicts=16&highlight=on)_?

Comment: Якщо подобається так, то пишіть так. З огляду на моє розуміння я написав так, як написав. Мені більше подобається слово наказ. Те що наказ потрібно давати якимось методом - це не обов'язково уточнювати. Інших варіянтів просто не буде окрім уведення. Теоретично слово наказ можна замінити на інші типу команда або інструкція чи та ж вказівка. Але суть від цього не змінюється. Чим наказ гірший ...

Comment: Це дуже важливе питання для всіх людей, які хоч якось пов'язані із IT сферою, студентів та вчителів, тут має бути обов'язково більш канонічна і аргументована відповідь.

Comment: Якщо напишете чого саме не вистачає, то спробую пояснити детальніше.

Comment: Моє питання є достатнім і це не заклик до кращої відповіді - це пояснення чого ваша відповідь не підходить. Пояснення мені не потрібні.

Comment: Справа в тому, що я описав так, як вважаю, що пояснює суть. Мені важко зрозуміти що ще треба додати. Потрібна підказка з вашого боку чого вам не вистачає в моїй відповіді.

Comment: У вашому тексті лише одне запитання: Як найкраще перекласти “command prompt”? Інших немає. Я описав як я перекладаю. В мене теж є невеликий досвід в інформаційних технологіях. Вважаю, що досвід достатній, щоб довести, що в даному випадку мій переклад правильний. Але якщо мій текст не доводить цього, то мені потрібна ваша допомога, щоб зрозуміти чого не вистачає для пояснення.

Comment: "Може вже краще запрошення до введення команди?" - тут також хочу звернути увагу, що в словосполученні command prompt не йдеться про введення

Answer (score 3):

**Інтерпретатор командного рядка**

> **Command Prompt** — програма для інтерпретації командного рядка, доступна в більшості операційних систем Windows. Він використовується для виконання введених команд. Більшість із цих команд автоматизують завдання за допомогою скриптів та пакетних файлів, виконують розширені адміністративні функції та усувають неполадки чи вирішують певні види проблем Windows.

[image: command prompt]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe

Ось так виглядає стандарне вікно Terminal на Mac OS.
[image]

Тут **terminal prompts** - це **підказки** доступних до використання **команд**.

Comment: Цитата, я так розумію, [звідси](https://uk.fbcpasorobles.org/command-prompt-2625840-8684) (в ідеалі варто зазначати джерела цитат: і заради авторського права, і задля того, щоб можна було оцінити надійність першоджерела). Зазначу, що це (автоматичний?) переклад [цієї](https://fbcpasorobles.org/command-prompt-2625840-8684), але конкретно той абзац виглядає пристойно й доречно. (Хоча словосполучення command prompt можна трактувати й ширше, ніж у цій цитаті, — як загальне поняття, а не як назву конкретної програми від Microsoft, але запропонований варіант перекладу, як на мене, ідеальний.)

Comment: @Sasha дякую :) На відміну від unix-систем, в яких можна отримати прямий доступ до ядра системи через термінальну консольну програму, як от, наприклад, через Terminal можна надавати команди ядру Mac OSx, в операційних системах на основі Windows такої можливості немає і необхідно використовувати інтерпретатор командного рядка cmd.exe

Comment: Не розумію яка користь від знімку екрана англ. вікі.

Comment: @Yola Я би міг перекласти текст та додати скрін свого терміналу. Але для наочності вирішив навести першоджерело. Щоб всім було зрозуміліше, що Command Prompt - це комп'ютерна утиліта і на це треба зважати при перекладі словосполучення. Iншими словами, це технічний термін, а не загальна фраза.

Comment: Я помітив, що на сайтах цієї мережі не прийнято давати картинки першоджерел. Зазвичай обмежуються посиланнями. Мені здається цей випадок не незвичайний.

Comment: Скажіть, а якби Майкрософт назвала це приладдя не *Command Prompt*, а, скажімо, *Dancing Firefly*, то чи його теж варто було б перекласти як *інтерпретатор командного рядка*?

Comment: @Yola так, розумію на що ви натякаєте, якби назва не містила сенсу або не відповідала функціональності приладдя.. як от танцюючий вогник. Але ж відповідає. А щодо вашого прикладу вийде гарне питання, на зразок: як слід перекладати англійське Firewall українською ;)

Comment: Я не певен на 100%, що мав на увазі автор запитання, але, мені здається, command prompt краще в першу чергу розуміти все-таки як загальне поняття (і вже в другу — як назву конкретної програми від Microsoft). Принаймні розглядати серію подібних словосполучень: command prompt, bash prompt тощо.

Comment: Щодо terminal prompt у macOS… Наскільки я розумію, найчастіше під цим розуміють саме оту інформацію перед `$` в командній оболонці (найчастіше в bash), як-от у [1](//medium.com/@ajaykarwal/4d80163be6a1), [2](//mattmazur.com/2012/01/27/how-to-change-your-default-terminal-prompt). Але в окремих випадках значення може бути й інше, наприклад [`GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT`](//git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTERMINALPROMPTcode) визначає, чи можна питати в користувача невідомі параметри (наприклад пароль); «terminal prompts disabled» з Вашого скриншоту було саме про `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT`.

Comment: Майже так. Замість bash в мене zsh, який використовує % для позначення початку командного рядка. Даємо команду homebrew оновити софт до останньої версії: brew update і скрипт homebrew починає по черзі звертатися до встановлених програм, спочатку до git-. Але він відповідає, що не може розпізнати ім'я користувача, яке збережено в osxkeychain та повідомляє,

Comment: що підказки терміналу для гіт вимкнені.

Answer (score 2):

[Ґуґл каже:](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=uk&text=prompt&op=translate)

> 2. assist or encourage (a hesitating speaker) to say something.
>    "“And the picture?” he prompted"

Гадаю, що саме це значення використане в *command prompt*.

Можна використати слово [зазив](http://sum.in.ua/s/zazyv):

> **ЗАЗИ́В**, у, *чол., рідко.* Те саме, що запрошення. — *Коли ти кличеш мене до себе, то я радуюсь твойому* [твоєму] *зазиву і радо піду за тобою* (Іван Франко, VI, 1951, 116).

- **Командний зазив**

Те, що слово *зазив* рідко вживане може допомогти уникнути платунини.

РЕД: Спав на думку ще один варіант:

- **Запит команди**

Comment: перша редакцiя вашої відповіді була веселою) а тепер - цiкавий варiант. Бачу за вашим посиланням, що словники Google не бездоганнi, адже "пiдказка" це "hint" https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=uk&text=hint&op=translate

Comment: Мабуть, Prompt заслуговує окремого від command треду. Бо слово це не просте і може використовуватись у багатьох значеннях.